# Why clang-tidy reports about uninitialized fields, if they are inited?

Tags: c++, clang++, clang-tidy, fmt, spdlog

I reported [issue](https://github.com/gabime/spdlog/issues/3037) to spdlog project where I provided clang-tidy report about uninitialized fields. It looks like this:

```
/Users/user/projects/github/spdlog/myapp/../artifacts/include/spdlog/fmt/bundled/core.h:2955:15: warning: 5 uninitialized fields at the end of the constructor call [clang-analyzer-optin.cplusplus.UninitializedObject]
 2955 |         types_{
      |               ^
/Users/user/projects/github/spdlog/myapp/../artifacts/include/spdlog/fmt/bundled/core.h:732:7: note: uninitialized field 'this->context_.num_args_'
  732 |   int num_args_;
      |       ^~~~~~~~~
/Users/user/projects/github/spdlog/myapp/../artifacts/include/spdlog/fmt/bundled/core.h:733:15: note: uninitialized pointer 'this->context_.types_'
  733 |   const type* types_;
      |               ^~~~~~
/Users/user/projects/github/spdlog/myapp/../artifacts/include/spdlog/fmt/bundled/core.h:432:15: note: uninitialized pointer 'this->context_.basic_format_parse_context::format_str_.data_'
  432 |   const Char* data_;
      |               ^~~~~
/Users/user/projects/github/spdlog/myapp/../artifacts/include/spdlog/fmt/bundled/core.h:433:10: note: uninitialized field 'this->context_.basic_format_parse_context::format_str_.size_'
  433 |   size_t size_;
      |          ^~~~~
/Users/user/projects/github/spdlog/myapp/../artifacts/include/spdlog/fmt/bundled/core.h:657:7: note: uninitialized field 'this->context_.basic_format_parse_context::next_arg_id_'
  657 |   int next_arg_id_;
      |       ^~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/user/projects/github/spdlog/myapp/main.cpp:6:19: note: Calling constructor for 'basic_format_string<char, int>'
    6 |     spdlog::error("Some error message with arg: {}", 1);
      |                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/user/projects/github/spdlog/myapp/../artifacts/include/spdlog/fmt/bundled/core.h:3155:5: note: Taking true branch
 3155 |     if constexpr (detail::count_named_args<Args...>() ==
      |     ^
/Users/user/projects/github/spdlog/myapp/../artifacts/include/spdlog/fmt/bundled/core.h:3159:47: note: Calling constructor for 'format_string_checker<char, fmt::detail::error_handler, int>'
 3159 |       detail::parse_format_string<true>(str_, checker(s, {}));
      |                                               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/user/projects/github/spdlog/myapp/../artifacts/include/spdlog/fmt/bundled/core.h:2955:15: note: 5 uninitialized fields at the end of the constructor call
 2955 |         types_{
      |               ^
 2956 |             mapped_type_constant<Args,
      |             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 2957 |                                  basic_format_context<Char*, Char>>::value...} {
      |                                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

`main.cpp` code looks quite simpe:

```
#include <spdlog/spdlog.h>

int main() 
{
    spdlog::error("Some error message with arg: {}", 1);
}
```

Then I started code reading to understand why variables are not inited and how can I fix that. Unfortunately, I didn't realise the root of the warnings.

`spdlog::error("Some error message with arg: {}", 1);` leads to calling error function. It has the following signature:

```
template<typename... Args>
inline void error(format_string_t<Args...> fmt, Args &&... args);
```

Here `fmt` argument has to be created - leads to calling `format_string_t` constructor:

```
template<typename... Args>
using format_string_t = fmt::format_string<Args...>;
```

`fmt::format_string` expands to:

```
template<typename... Args>
using format_string = basic_format_string<char, type_identity_t<Args>...>;
```

`basic_format_string` class looks like this:

```
template<typename Char, typename... Args>
class basic_format_string
{
  ...
public:
    template<typename S, FMT_ENABLE_IF(std::is_convertible<const S &, basic_string_view<Char>>::value)>
    FMT_CONSTEVAL FMT_INLINE basic_format_string(const S &s)
        : str_(s)
    {
        ...
        if constexpr (detail::count_named_args<Args...>() == detail::count_statically_named_args<Args...>())
        {
            using checker = detail::format_string_checker<Char, detail::error_handler, remove_cvref_t<Args>...>;
            detail::parse_format_string<true>(str_, checker(s, {}));
        }
    }
  ...
}
```

Here `format_string_checker` constructor is calling:

```
template <typename Char, typename ErrorHandler, typename... Args>
class format_string_checker {
  ...

 public:
  explicit FMT_CONSTEXPR format_string_checker(
      basic_string_view<Char> format_str, ErrorHandler eh)
      : context_(format_str, num_args, types_, eh),
        parse_funcs_{&parse_format_specs<Args, parse_context_type>...},
        types_{
            mapped_type_constant<Args,
                                 basic_format_context<Char*, Char>>::value...} {
  }
  ...
}
```

So, `context_` constructor is calling as well - `compile_parse_context<Char, ErrorHandler>`

```
private:
    int num_args_;
    const type *types_;
    using base = basic_format_parse_context<Char, ErrorHandler>;

public:
    explicit FMT_CONSTEXPR compile_parse_context(
        basic_string_view<Char> format_str, int num_args, const type *types, ErrorHandler eh = {}, int next_arg_id = 0)
        : base(format_str, eh, next_arg_id)
        , num_args_(num_args)
        , types_(types)
    {}
  ...
}
```

`num_args_` and `types_` are inited. I thought maybe I'm missing something and somehow default constructor is calling, and members don't have default values. However, even I set default values for these member - `clang-tidy` reports about the same problem.

Am I missing something or `clang-tidy` reports about that problem by mistake?

---

**spdlog**: `v1.13.0`

clang information

```
user@mac build % clang++ --version                                 
Apple clang version 15.0.0 (clang-1500.1.0.2.5)
Target: arm64-apple-darwin23.2.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
user@mac build % clang-tidy --version                                 
LLVM (http://llvm.org/):
  LLVM version 19.0.0git
  Optimized build.
```

---

**UPD.O**:

- I tried to specify `core.h` in `HeaderFilterRegex` to not analyze it. The same result.
- I managed to suppress this warning by adding `/* NOLINTBEGIN */` and `/* NOLINTEND */` before `FMT_BEGIN_DETAIL_NAMESPACE` and after `FMT_END_DETAIL_NAMESPACE` (wrap `compile_parse_context` class) - it works. However, it is bad practice to patch 3rd party library and even worse do that without confidence the problem doesn't exist.

Comment: Do you still get reports if you specify spdlog's header installation directory as a system directory? `clang-tidy ... -extra-arg=-std=c++23 -- -isystem spdlog-install-dir/include -I other/dir ...`  - That seems to make it quiet for me

Comment: First, please fix the question title.  It has an obvious typo ("Wh"->"Why"), and even after that is fixed, it is ungrammatical.  Such a title gives the impression of carelessness; why should I care about your question if you don't?  Second, this looks like it might be turned into a good question about how `clang-tidy` handles initializers like `types_{mapped_type_constants...}`, but the code example is currently much too long and incomplete.  Try to create an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) by cutting what you have down to the bare minimum.

Comment: _"However, it is bad practice to patch 3rd party library"_ - It depends on how you do it. I usually start by creating an issue in the upstream repo like you did and then see if I can fix the issue without spending more than a few hours on it. If I manage to do that, I make a pull request. In this case it seems like the issue comes from `{fmt}` 9 and I see that they actually upgraded to 10, but then reverted that upgrade.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Thanks for the advice. I think your suggestion about placing `spdlog` to system directories just leads to avoiding `clang-tidy` analysing system headers and because of that warnings might be disappeared. Related to `fmt` library - yes, I noticed that too. However, I don't see any significant changes in `v10` which can affect on warnings.

Comment: @ScottMcPeak It is exactly the typo, but not carelessness to the question=) I fixed that and a bit cut the code snippets. I hope it has become more clear.

Comment: @slinkin Yes, telling `clang-tidy` that it's a system header makes it skip analyzing it. If you feel uncomfortable with that, do a proper analysis yourself _once_ and if you think it's a false positive, only _then_ add it as a system header. If you think there is a real problem, add a more specific issue to the upsteam repo where you describe how the uninitialized fields become a real problem (that is, they are read while being uninitialized - being uninitialized but not read is _not_ a problem). I'd use AddressSanitizer and UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer to help with the analysis.